# C typedef in declaration

Tags: c, variable-declaration

```
typedef long a;
extern a int c;
```

Hi the above code gives errors like `In function 'main':
Line 7: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers`

but when the same 'a' in 2nd line is replaced by long it works perfectly fine.
This works perfectly fine

`typedef long a;
extern long int c;`

Please explain why does this happen

Comment: As you can see [here][1] long is already a type


  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types

Comment: ,`long` is treated as an abbreviation of `long int`. `a int` meant e.g `long int int`.

Answer (score 4):

`long int` is a type name.

`type-alias-name type-name` is parsed as two types even if `type-alias-name` is an alias for `long` and `type-name` is `int`.

Answer (score 3):

A `typedef` is not a macro.

Once you have a `typedef` you no longer have the **text** "int" that can just be coalesced with the **text** "long" to make a new type. It is its own, first-class type that will conflict with another type in the same declaration.